# How to know which type to instantiate from something like JSON?

Tags: swift, generics

My app loads a JSON file at launch. The JSON file includes instructions to create various instances of different types. As a basic example, I have a protocol called `BasicType` with some extensions to make some built-in Swift types conform to it:

```
protocol BasicType {

}

extension Int: BasicType { }

extension Float: BasicType { }

extension String: BasicType { }
```

I also have a dictionary which maps these type 'names' (as found in the JSON) to the types themselves:

```
let basicTypes = [
    "integer": Int.self,
    "float": Float.self,
    "string": String.self
] as [String : BasicType.Type]
```

When I'm loading `BasicType`s from the JSON, I look up the name specified by the JSON using the dictionary above to know which type to instantiate (in reality, the protocol also defines initialisers, so this is possible). I have some other protocols in addition to `BasicType` which work in exactly the same way, and each one gets its own dictionary map.

For example, my JSON might include an array of `BasicType`s I want to instantiate:

```
{
    "basic_types": [{
        "type": "integer",
        ...
    }, {
        "type": "integer",
        ...
    }, {
        "type": "string",
        ...
    }, {
        "type": "float",
        ...
    }]
}
```

The ellipses denote other attributes which are passed to the initialiser, like what value the integer should be. In actuality, these are custom structs and classes which take various properties. In my Swift code, I open up the `basic_types` array, look at the `type` key for each JSON object, look up the appropriate types and initialise them. So my loaded array would include two `Int`s, a `String` and a `Float`.

This is similar to how UIKit instantiates views from a storyboard, for example. The view's class name is stored in the storyboard, and in this case presumably it uses something like `NSClassFromString` to perform the mapping. I don't want to rely on the Objective-C runtime though.

---

The problem with this approach is that it's difficult to look up the name of a type if I already have the type or instance, as I have to inefficiently iterate the dictionary to search.

Instead, I thought a better solution might be to include each type's name (or 'type identifier') statically as a variable in the type itself, and then generate the type maps from that. So, I created a new protocol:

```
protocol TypeIdentifiable {
    static var typeIdentifier: String { get }
}
```

And made `BasicType` (and all the other similar protocols) inherit from it:

```
protocol BasicType: TypeIdentifiable {

}
```

Which means I need to provide the names directly in the types themselves:

```
extension Int: BasicType {
    static let typeIdentifier = "integer"
}

extension Float: BasicType {
    static let typeIdentifier = "float"
}

extension String: BasicType {
    static let typeIdentifier = "string"
}
```

I made a function (which compiles) which I intended to generically take a protocol conforming to `TypeIdentifiable` and including an array of types, and produce a dictionary containing the mapping:

```
func typeMap<T : TypeIdentifiable>(_ types: [T.Type]) -> [String : T.Type] {
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: types.map { type in
        (key: type.typeIdentifier, value: type)
    })
}
```

I can then replace the dictionary literal with:

```
let basicTypes = typeMap([
    Int.self,
    Float.self,
    String.self
] as [BasicType.Type])
```

This way, if I have a type I can easily get its name by accessing its static property, and if I have the name I can get the type through the generated dictionary.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

> error: cannot convert value of type '[BasicType.Type]' to expected argument type '[_.Type]'

I think using a protocol as a generic type is forbidden in Swift, which probably makes it impossible to do what I'm trying to do.

My question is: *Is* there a way of doing what I'm trying to do? Otherwise, on a more general level, is there a better way of knowing what types to instantiate from something like JSON?

Comment: It's hard to follow your question without some concrete examples. Can you provide a sample JSON and what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I've added a JSON snippet and a couple paragraphs underneath. It's hard to keep it brief and understandable without going into too much superfluous detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [SR-3038](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3038) and is roughly "as designed." Protocols do not conform to themselves, so they cannot fulfill generic requirements. `BasicType` cannot be `T` because `BasicType` is a protocol. Why? Well, imagine I've written this code (which I expect is really similar to what you want to write):

```
protocol P {
    init()
}

func makeOne<T:P>(what: T.Type) -> T {
    return T.init()
}
```

Awesome. That's legal. Now, if protocols conformed to themselves, I could write this code:

```
makeOne(what: P.self)
```

What `init` should that call? Swift fixes this impasse by only allowing concrete types to conform to protocols. Since `BasicType` does not conform to `BasicType`, it also does not conform to `TypeIdentifiable`, and cannot be `T`.

So what do we do?

- First and most important-top-of-the-list: Do you actually need this to be generic? How many times do you actually plan to use it for radically different JSON formats? Could you just write the parsing code directly (ideally with the new `Codeable`)? The tears that have been spilled trying to write complex JSON parsers to parse simple JSON formats could flood WWDC. My rule of thumb is to avoid making things generic unless I already know at least 3 different ways it will be used. (If that happens later, I refactor to generic when I have the examples.) You just don't know enough about the problem until have have several concrete examples and your generic solution will probably be wrong anyway.
- OK, let's assume this really is a very general JSON format you have to parse where you have no idea what's going to be in it (maybe like the NIB format you mention). The first and most obvious answer: Use your existing solution. Your concern is that it's hard to look them up backwards (type->identifier), but that's trivial to write a method to make that easy. Unless you have many thousands, possibly millions, of types, the difference in time is beyond trivial; linear search can even be faster than dictionaries for small collections.
- Next in line is to just write `typeMap` for each protocol (i.e. explicitly for `BasicType` rather than making it generic. There are several cases in stdlib where they do this. Sometimes you just have to do that.
- And of course you could create a `TypeDefinition` struct that holds the info (like a type eraser). In practice this really just moves the problem around. Eventually you'll need to duplicate some code if there are a bunch of protocols.

But almost always when I head down this kind of road, I discover it was way over-engineered and just writing the silly code directly is the easy and scalable solution.

And of course look carefully at the new `JSONDecoder` in Swift 4. You want to be moving in that direction if you can anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I currently have nine literal dictionaries in my source, all mapping names loaded from JSON to a type of a specific protocol. The dictionaries have as few as two entries and as many as about fifty; you're correct in that the situation is not currently that dire (it's certainly manageable), and the reverse lookup isn't frequent enough to be slow, but I was disappointed when I realised my otherwise-clever solution didn't work. Would you say what I am currently doing then is basically a 'best practise'? Are there any other ways you know of to refer to native types from JSON?

Comment: Generally that's what `NSKeyedArchiver` is for, so I tend to use that (and `NSKeyedArchiver` supports Swift value types in Swift 4). I would recommend exploring `Decodeable`. I've had good luck with it so far (though sometimes you need to dig deep to use it in non-obvious ways). My experience is that having lots of protocols is an anti-pattern, and you're better off using structs/type-erasers. It's hard to see what the final goal of this system is. Almost always (and literally last week in my code), I find that rethinking the problem from the top gets rid of much of the madness.

Comment: I'm not saying you're building anything wrong, but I will say that reinventing `NSKeyedArchiver` is probably not ideal if you can avoid it. I'd just use the tool we have unless this really needs to be in JSON. (JSON is convenient, but is often applied to things where it is not a particularly good fit.)

Comment: I should probably mention that the JSON is used, unmodified, on multiple platforms, which is why I'm using that rather than `NSKeyedArchiver`. I'll look into `Decodeable` as part of my Swift 4 migration, though I didn't immediately see any solution to the general problem (if I want to load an array of objects conforming to a protocol, how does it know which types of the protocol to instantiate?) Having said that, it would be nice to move onto a more official way of using JSON, so if I can't find a solution I'll probably post another question!